# Is there a possibility to restructure a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

```
Access Risk ID User ID
    SOD05       144
    SOD05A      74
    SOD06       140
    SOD07A      50
    SOD08A      30
    ... ...
    SOD77B      30
    SOD78       30
    SOD78A      30
    SOD78B      30
    SOD80       66
```

Hi all,

I have the above pivot. Instead of the count of User IDs I want each User ID related to the column Access Risk ID to be listed (so 144 rows for SOD05)..........

I have not found an answer to this issue on Stackoverflow. If one of you could help me that would be extremely helpful
Please help~!
Code I used:

```
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(dfpivot, index='Access Risk ID', values = ['User ID'], aggfunc='count')
pivot1
```

Input:

```
| User ID      | Access Risk ID | Executed within the Q? |
|--------------|----------------|:----------------------:|
| ACHINE       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| ACHINE       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| AHOFMA       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| AHOFMA       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| AZILZ        | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| AZILZ        | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| BKACZM       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| BKACZM       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| CAFERR       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| CAFERR       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| CAUTRE       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| CAUTRE       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| CDIERKES     | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| CDIERKES     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| CHEISE       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| CHEISE       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| CMOLDO       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| CMOLDO       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| DAYBEK       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| DAYBEK       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| DCHLUDOVA    | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| DCHLUDOVA    | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| DDIC         | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| DDIC         | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| DVDSTRAETEN  | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| DVDSTRAETEN  | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| EGAVRY       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| EGAVRY       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| ETROCH       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| ETROCH       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| EVDHAEGEN    | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| EVDHAEGEN    | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_BASIS     | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| FF_BASIS     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_BASIS_CON | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_BASIS_CON | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_CTAC      | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_CTAC      | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_01  | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_01  | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_02  | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| FF_DEBUG_02  | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_FIN | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| FF_DEBUG_FIN | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_PRD | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_PRD | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_RET | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_RET | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_SRC | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUG_SRC | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUGT    | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_DEBUGT    | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_FIN       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_FIN       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_FINT      | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FF_FINT      | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FPHILIPS     | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| FPHILIPS     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| FSOYLU       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| FSOYLU       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| FVDVAEREN    | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| FVDVAEREN    | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| GANGAROVA    | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| GANGAROVA    | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| JDELANG      | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| JDELANG      | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| JDHONDT      | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| JDHONDT      | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| JKIMML       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| JKIMML       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| KAGRAS       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| KAGRAS       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| KFOUCA       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| KFOUCA       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| KMUELL       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| KMUELL       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| KREGIN       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| KREGIN       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| LBUGGENHOUT  | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| LBUGGENHOUT  | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| LBUYCK       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| LBUYCK       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| LCROMBRUGGE  | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| LCROMBRUGGE  | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| LLAMER       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| LLAMER       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| LPUTMANS     | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| LPUTMANS     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| LSTANI       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| LSTANI       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| MDEMETSER    | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| MDEMETSER    | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| MIGNACEK     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| MIGNACEK     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| MINDEN       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| MINDEN       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| MMARKO       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| MMARKO       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| MVERVR       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| MVERVR       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| MVINCK       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| MVINCK       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| NAGARC       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| NAGARC       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| OSS          | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| OSS          | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| PAUGUS       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| PAUGUS       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| PCRAEN       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| PCRAEN       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| PCUMAL       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| PCUMAL       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| PSTEPPE      | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| PSTEPPE      | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| RPEREZ15     | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| RPEREZ15     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| RWILLE       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| RWILLE       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| SCOLSON      | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SCOLSON      | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SEYLEN       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| SEYLEN       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| SKOENN       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SKOENN       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SLECLERE     | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SLECLERE     | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| SMARTE       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SMARTE       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| SPOSSE       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SPOSSE       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| SPULLI       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SPULLI       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| STHUR        | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| STHUR        | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| STWYNS       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| STWYNS       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SWOLF        | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| SWOLF        | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| VCUBIA       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| VCUBIA       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
| VINBOM       | SOD05          |          TRUE          |
| VINBOM       | SOD05          |          FALSE         |
```

I want a pivot like this:

```
Access Risk ID  User ID
SOD05           AHOFMA
                AZILZ
                BKACZM
                EGAVRY
                ETROCH
                FSOYLU
                JDELANG
                JKIMML
                KMUELL
                LSTANI
                MINDEN
                MVERVR
                MVINCK
                PCUMAL
                SCOLSON
                SKOENN
                STHUR
                STWYNS
                SWOLF
```

Comment: Can you share the starting sample DF and your desired DF after this change? What you've shared here is merely what you DONT want and the code that produced what you don't want, which isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: It'd be great to get an excerpt of your `dfpivot` as well. I think you might just need [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I suggested in the comment, you can use groupby:

```
print(df.groupby(['Access Risk ID', 'User ID']).sum())
```

The sum in this example sums the remaining columns (in your case "Executed within the Q?") and you'll get:

```
                        Executed within the Q?
Access Risk ID User ID
SOD05          ACHINE                        1
               AHOFMA                        2
               AZILZ                         2
               BKACZM                        2
               CAFERR                        1
...                                        ...
               STHUR                         2
               STWYNS                        2
               SWOLF                         2
               VCUBIA                        1
               VINBOM                        1
```